# Changed SSH default port and disabled root login. Client didn't save the new port can't login/connect to it now

Tags: ssh, port, login, root, putty

Working on my centos server. Connecting via putty. Changed SSH default port and disabled root login. But the client didn't save the new port and defaulted back to 22 (my new one was 42650 or something like that). So now I can't login/connect to it.

Comment: I would run nmap against the box, telling it to check all open ports. That should tell you what ports are open, and i think it would tell you which port you need. Something like 'nmap -p 1-65535 <target>'.

Comment: I'm quite new to this. Walk me through what you are talking about?

Comment: The server is hosted on cloudatcost so it's not physically here.

Comment: I figured out your suggestion baumgart. Unfortunately the ranges that it would be in are all unknown although it also says Not shown: 108 closed ports so I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: Just login from the console and fix it.

Comment: That's the point! I can't connect to it to fix it... I don't know the port to use with the ip address...

Comment: http://puu.sh/733i6.png See picture for refrence.

Comment: I scanned your server given the IP address that was included with your screenshot but couldn't find any open SSH ports. Since you're using Windows, here is the nmap utility if you'd like to give it a try: http://nmap.org/download.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, ***Bad Admin! BAD!** -- You made a change without documenting it.
Hopefully you have learned an important lesson about documenting your changes.

Now, to get out of this mess you find yourself in you have three options:

1. **Connect on the physical console and fix the problem**
   Per your comments this is a cloud server, so you may not have a physical (virtual) console.
   If you have no way of logging in "on the console" this obviously won't work for you.
2. **Port Scan your box with `nmap` and figure out which listening port is SSH**
   Pretty straightforward: `nmap -p 1-65535 <target>` like [baumgart said](https://serverfault.com/questions/576654/changed-ssh-default-port-and-disabled-root-login-client-didnt-save-the-new-por#comment673504_576654).
   You will get a list of all open ports on the server. Presumably your server is well-configured and you can account for every port that is listening, so the one you can't account for is where SSH is.
   (If your server is *not* well-configured you will have many unaccounted ports - try each of them until you find SSH, then *audit your configuration* so you know what's listening on your server and what ports should be open...)
3. **Re-Image the system**
   Since this is a cloud server (again, per your comments) you can wipe it out and rebuild it from your cloud provider's stock image.
   Obviously you will have to restore any customizations from your backups if you go this route (you do have backups, right?). If you *don't* have backups (***Bad Admin! BAD!**) and have substantial customizations this may not be a desirable option.

Comment: Got it to work with #1 and #2. (with some help from cloudatcost :D)

Comment: ...and you now have a pen and a yellow legal pad (or stack of post-it notes) to scribble changes on as you're making them, right? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are on Windows, you'll need to download the nmap utility: 
http://nmap.org/download.html

In the COMMAND field, type in: nmap -T4 Aggressive -A -v -f -p 1-65535

This can be a very long scan, upwards of 30 minutes to complete, but it will give you the most detailed output for any unresponsive SSH ports that might be available.

If you see a port that appears to be SSH, you can try using Putty to connect to it. I would select a verbose output option to get more information from it.